# Styling only promoted widgets using QT Creator

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt and have been designing forms using Qt Creator.  I've noticed that I can apply styles for specific widgets in the form's stylesheet, and it will style every widget on the form.  For example "QPushButton{color: red;}" will make all the QPushButtons on the form have red text.

Is there a way to only apply styles to certain groups of widgets?  For example, if I promote a QPushButton and call it MyButton, how can I set styles only for MyButtons.  I would expect to be able to do something like "MyButton{color: green;}" but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do (preferably using Qt Creator)?  I can't seem to find an example of this anywhere, but maybe it's because I'm not using the correct terminology.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of options for specifying selectors in style sheets. They are [documented here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

One that I use (that is hinted to in the [official style sheet reference document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#q1)) is
**|=**

```
QPushButton[objectName|="somePrefix_"]
```

I use this to select items that have the same object name prefix. You could of course achieve a similar thing by applying a stylesheet to a panel containing the buttons you want to style differently but this can get tricky.

Comment: **This is it.** This approach has the added bonus of being displayed both from within Qt (Creator|Designer) *and* at application runtime. The only alternative approach is to promote the desired widgets (e.g., to an empty subclass) and then select and style those widgets by that promoted type – which, due to outstanding issues in Qt (Creator|Designer), is displayed at application runtime but *not* from within Qt (Creator|Designer). `</bangs_head_repeatedly_on_keyboard>`

Answer (score 2):

IIRC that should work, but creator might not show the preview correctly as it is not instantiating your button. Personally I think working with a global .css file that gets loaded at startup works better than applying single styles on each element in creator.

Use `QApplication::setStyleSheet()` to set a global stylesheet